# small application in visual c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I started to use visual c++  few days ago to edit an open source project ,[SFX7zip](ftp://ftp.altap.cz/pub/altap/salamand/sfx7zip.zip)
,inside the zip folder/release i got 2 exe compiled already(in the size of 27.5 kb and 19 kb(used upx)),

everything worked fine i tried to compile them (with VS 6.00 and VS 2010) ,both them gave me a big size exe (75 KB and 65 KB), i am sure that the pre compiled exes are not used other tools to compress (except upx for one of them , according to the help inside the zip) why these size are different for me

size is still a problem for me (even in this century ) and i am using it for a setup app,

what are the mistakes i have done when compiling (or what tool or what version i have to use to compile this source)

Comment: Are you compiling with the [debug configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx), by chance?

Comment: sorry i am very vary new to vc++

Comment: If Visual Studio looks like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9rNebBXDgwA/Sw6tfvI2K3I/AAAAAAAAAjc/TJKvVF7-M_0/s1600/zoom+.PNG) with the word "Debug" in the drop-down menu (top right), try selecting "Release".